# Nullpointer Exception with Camera Intent on Android Kitkat

Tags: java, android, camera, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm using this code to handle Camera Intent on Android Kitkat or major. Everytime I take a photo, after taking it, I get a 
nullpointer exception:

> ```
>  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
> ```

Code in onActivityResult:

```
 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    final String location = data.getDataString();
     Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException s) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mPhotoview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Edit, I get the error on this line:

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri));
```

After this error, the app crashes.
I think it can't get the Uri, how I can solve this? Thanks in advance.

Solved by sourrounding everything with a try / catch block and on:

```
catch (NullPointerException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Log.d("error", "error");
mPhotoview.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) data.getParcelableExtra("data"));
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing your error?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: So what is null? Check before use.

Comment: What are you refering for, greenapps?

Comment: You have a NullPointerException. So in that code line you use a pointer that is null. So find out which pointer is null before you use that line. And if null then do not use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera app does not have to return the `Uri` where the image is stored in the `Intent` handed to `onActivityResult()`. If you provided the `Uri` via `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, use that. If you did not use `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, you will have a thumbnail `Bitmap` in the `data` extra on the `Intent`.

Comment: I didn't used the EXTRA_OUTPUT, could you explain better the second way, please?

Comment: When I do data.getData() I'm using my intent declared in "onActivityResult"

Comment: @BitleApps: "could you explain better the second way, please?" -- `data.getParcelableExtra("data")` is a `Bitmap` that is a thumbnail-sized photo.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand.. What I should substitute in my code to make it display a bitmap image on the imageview "mPhotoview"? Or just to trepass this error, I can't solve this. I'm sorry.

Comment: @BitleApps: "What I should substitute in my code to make it display a bitmap image on the imageview "mPhotoview"?" -- `mPhotoview.setImageBitmap(data.getParcelableExtra("data"))` would be one approach, assuming that `mPhotoview` is an `ImageView`.